# How to get language of website in selenium(python)?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, tags, chrome-options

I set the language in Selenium using: `chrome_options.addargument("--lang=en")`.

However, in test I need to check that language is really English.

Maybe I can check it from `<html lang='...'>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to get the browser language as a string:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
language = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html").get_attribute('lang')
```

Hope that helps